# Jest: node.js SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, jestjs, automated-tests, syntax-error, importerror

I have just started learning `jest` testing and created a sample application to get familiar with `jest` testing. However, I am getting following error...

[image]

Language.js

```js
const calculateTip = (total, percentage) => {
    return total + ((percentage / 100) * total) + 1;
};

export {
    calculateTip,
}
```

package.json

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.18.2"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "main": "src/app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node src/app.js",
        "test": "cls && env-cmd -f ./envs/test.env jest --watchAll"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "jest": "^29.2.2",
        "supertest": "^6.3.1"
    }
}
```

I have tried googling for the solution but no luck so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Node.js supports esm syntax only from v16, but jest doesn't support it yet.
Therefore, you have 2 choices:

1. Don't use the esm syntax (`import` / `export`)
2. Add [jest-babel](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel) with it's config to transpile (convert) esm syntax to cjs one.

Comment: Thank you @felixmosh, Although this worked, there are so many depreciation warnings while installing the packages. I had to delete the `node_modules` directory and install the package before running the `npm install` command.

Answer (score 7):

Jest now ships with experimental support for ECMAScript Modules (ESM):

https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

The simplest way forward is to update your test script to execute `node` with `--experimental-vm-modules` e.g.

```
node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js
```

or to add an environment variable to the test script

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest
```

See the link above for more details.

Comment: The solution is correct. Just to add, in Windows to set NODE_OPTIONS env you may want to use this package: https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by installing [jest-babel](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel) and then creating `babel.config.cjs` in your root directory and pasting the following into it:

```
//babel.config.cjs
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

```
...
//package.json
"type": "module"

//tsconfig.json
...
"target": "esnext", 
"module": "commonjs", 
...
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to you package.json in scripts:

"test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest"

when you run 'npm test', it'll trigger above. 'cross-env' is added so it will run in any shell otherwise not needed in bash.

If you're in bash, then just run 'NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest'